# ListView with section header problem

Tags: android, listview, header

Hi I'm adding section headers for my listView, there are few methods on the web. Since I'm using simpleCursorAdapter to manage my listView, I adopted phil bogle's method. http://thebogles.com/blog/2010/02/section-headers-for-android-listviews/

The error occurred at this part of the code:

```
    listAdapter.setViewBinder( new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder()
    {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int
                                   columnIndex)
        {
              if (columnIndex == nDateIndex) {
                if (isHeaderVisible(cursor)) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     prevDate = dateString;
                    ((TextView) view).setText(dateString);
                } else {
                    ((TextView) view).setText("");
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the LogCat shows how they compare while I scroll up the list:

```
09-06 11:06:43.460: INFO/System.out(563): Sun, 05 Sep 2010 11:41:53  (dateString)
09-06 11:06:43.460: INFO/System.out(563): Wed, 01 Sep 2010 21:58:06  (preDate)
09-06 11:06:43.460: INFO/System.out(563): 120.0                      (record)
09-06 11:06:43.820: INFO/System.out(563): Sun, 05 Sep 2010 17:47:26  (dateString)
09-06 11:06:43.820: INFO/System.out(563): Sun, 05 Sep 2010 11:41:53  (preDate)
09-06 11:06:43.820: INFO/System.out(563): 112.0                      (record)
```

The correct output should be:
     **Sun, 05 Sep 2010**
     **112

     120**

But when I scroll up, the setViewValue calls 120 first and compare with preDate(show above), it becomes:
    **Sun, 05 Sep 2010

    112

    Sun, 05 Sep 2010

    120**

So how can I make the section headers fixed after creating the headers? Why setViewBinder been called while scrolling? Any suggestions on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might also take a look at very simple project here: http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/. Inspiration came from iOS's section list (comes out of the box in iOS).

Answer (score 2):

See the ListView with section headers widget here, this may help you. It works similarly to the default Contacts application.

http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

Comment: can you give a demo,it looks like only a view

Comment: A demo has now been put up into the project repository, and screenshots are now published.

Comment: thank you,i have run it very nice,but i found it some Characters not compatible with your code. i have give the image to your link about your app  http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/issues/detail?id=1

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I make the section headers fixed after creating the headers?

Have `isHeaderVisible()` work properly, I guess. Near as I can tell, that is where your problem lies.

> Why setViewBinder been called while scrolling?

Because rows are recycled when they are scrolled.

Comment: Ya, the isHeaderVisible() may got problem, because the comparison of preDate and dateString. preDate is used to check whether 2 items are different date. when first called, preDate will change to last record date in the end. But when scroll screen, the list of records are not called in sequence like I mentioned above.   The first record always show its title as header. the rest records compare with previous record if date diff then set title visible, use if(preDate.equals(dateString)) {view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); prevDate = dateString; } This only works well when set up the listView.

Comment: Problem is how to define preDate so that it can keep track while scrolling.